# Matplotlib don't show all ticks/labels with bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting a line with many points, matplotlib automatically hides some x-axis ticks/labels to make sure all labels can fit.

If I want to plot a bar chat with many points, is there anyway to make matplotlib think of the x-axis in the same as with a line plot? Right now it's trying to squeeze in all the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest specifiying the list of xtick labels :

```
plt.xticks([80,150,300]) ### In this case these are numbers, change them to your values
```